# How to pass text widget data from one screen to another screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

I Am trying to pass text widget data from one screen to another screen but I don't know how to do that in flutter.

I know how to do that from textfield and pass between screen. for example using a controller.

```
child: Text('Repetition', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),)),

 onPressed: ()=>{
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                builder:(context) => FingerGoalSt()))
          },
```

I want to pass the Repetition String into next screen.

In other platform it's easy but in flutter i have no idea as i am new to it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourString = 'Repetition'
child: Text(yourString, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),)),

 onPressed: ()=>{
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                builder:(context) => FingerGoalSt(yourString)))
          },
```

And in yours `FingerGoalSt` add a constructor with parameter.

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks as i am putting the slider value inside youString Variable

Comment: @KaziFaruque great! mind you mark my answer?

Answer (score 0):

**You can pass the variable in which you are storing the data**

```
    child: Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].get('name'), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),)),

 onPressed: ()=>{
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                builder:(context) => FingerGoalSt(snapshot.data.docs[index].get('name'))))
          },
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the below code

```
Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => FingerGoalSt(
                  textVal: "Repetition",
                ),
              ),
            );



class FingerGoalSt extends StatefulWidget {
final String textVal;
  const FingerGoalSt({Key key, this.textVal}) : super(key: key);
 @override
  _FingerGoalStState createState() => _FingerGoalStState();
}

class _FingerGoalStState extends State<FingerGoalSt> {

}
```

Please try this below example code

Example 1:

```
onPressed: () async {
   Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/FingerGoalSt',arguments:{"textvalue":"any text"});}


class FingerGoalSt extends StatelessWidget {
  const FingerGoalSt({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Map arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map;

    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:  Text('Value : ${arguments['textvalue']}'),
      ),
      body: Text("${arguments['textvalue']}"),
    );
  }
}
```

Example 2:

```
class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FirstScreenState createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SecondScreen(
                  dataList: ["Data"],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text(
            "Second Screen",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final List dataList;
  const SecondScreen({Key key, this.dataList}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          widget.dataList[0].toString(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For more info, please refer to this [link description](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)

Comment: I have seen this link but it is complicated and does not help with what i am trying to achieve . I just want to send the text widget data after the button click . but don't know how to reference it. thanks

Comment: @KaziFaruque. Please check my updated answer. It might help you. You can refer example code as well for more reference

Comment: Please check updated answer. You can follow either of the methods for navigation. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey, @Tejaswini Dev, I have tried your code, but it's passing the 'Data ' that you put inside dataList: [Data]. but i want pass whatever inside text widget for example child: Text(
            "Second Screen",
          ),

Comment: so basically I want to pass 'second screen' in SecondScreen any other text widget

Comment: Pass whatever text/string value as per your requirement. This is an example of how to pass arguments to the second screen. Data is an example code. You can try other two solutions also. Whichever is convenient for you. You can use it